# Azure development : Query from storage table can be sorted?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, c++-cli

Using Azure Data Table (`Azure::Data::Table` in C++ CLR) and `Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table`
using `TableEntity`, I can query the table storage using lines such as this:

```cpp
Azure::Pageable<TableEntity^>^ response = table->Query<TableEntity^>(filter, maxPerPage, selection, cancellationToken);

System::Collections::Generic::IEnumerator<TableEntity^>^ enumerator = response->GetEnumerator();
```

I have tried setting up the filters for some conditions, however I can't find any documentation on how to sort the result. Is it possible?

Comment: Use OrderBy(x => x.property) where property is the property you want for the sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Server side sorting is not supported for Table Storage. Query results are always sorted by PartitionKey and RowKey value.

For any kind of sorting, you would need to fetch the relevant data and do the sorting on client side.